# Firebase JavaScript value Change Events

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering how i can solve the following issue. I have a Record in the Firebase DB which i am monitoring. The App is a Sports Score So far so good.
When user loads the initial page i check if Game is Running or Stopped and so a few things.
below is a snipped of what i do

```
if(Clock.Status=='Running'){
            ......
        }
        else if(Clock.Status == 'Stopped'){
            .......
        }
```

So far so good when user hits the page for first time. But now i want to monitor if the ClockStatus changes

```
clockStatusRef = firebase.database().ref("games/"+gameId+"/Score/");
clockStatusRef.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
    var Clock = snapshot.val();
    var status = Clock.Status;

    // clock stopped - second scenario
    if(status=='Stopped'){
        stopTimer();
    }
    else if(status == 'Running'){
        // clock status running- third scenario
        firebase.database().ref('/.info/serverTimeOffset')
              .once('value')
              .then(function stv(data) {
                console.log('hi');
                serverTime = (data.val() + Date.now())/1000;
                var timeElapsed = serverTime - Clock.ClockStart;
                var totalCounts    = document.getElementById("total_counts");
                if(Clock.Timer > timeElapsed){
                    initTimer(Math.floor(Clock.Timer- timeElapsed),60);
                }
                else{
                    var Current_Clock = document.getElementById("count");
                    Current_Clock.innerHTML = '00:00';
                }
              }, function (err) {
                return err;
              });
    }
    console.log("Clock status changed: "+status);

});
```

for some strange reason on a change of status it starts with the main if

```
if(Clock.Status=='Running')
```

So i am wondering what am i missing and what is the best way to fix this so the first if is only run on the initial load and all subsequent will use the if's which handle status change of clock.

Here is the Json for `games/B8120ACD-DF51-A64A-A83E-556007522E80/Score/Clock`

```
{
  "ClockStart" : 1510535632, 
  "Period" : 1, 
  "Status" : "Stopped", 
  "Timer" : 900 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a single snippet of compiling code that reproduces the problem in your question. The `child_changed` handler you have now is incomplete, and I can't see how it related to the other code. Please also include a snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshot) at `Clock/Status`. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Here is the Json for games/B8120ACD-DF51-A64A-A83E-556007522E80/Score/Clock

{
  "ClockStart" : 1510535632,
  "Period" : 1,
  "Status" : "Stopped",
  "Timer" : 900
}

Comment: I enclose in original post the compler child_changed code

Answer (score 0):

You're listening one level higher in your JSON than your code expects.

Either change the code that gets the clock from the snapshot to:

```
var Clock = snapshot.val().Clock;
```

Or (better, because it requires less data transfer) listen one level lower in the tree:

```
clockStatusRef = firebase.database().ref("games/"+gameId+"/Score/Clock");
```

Comment: So if i monitor clockStatusRef = firebase.database().ref("games/"+gameId+"/Score/Clock/Status") wouldnt i just monitor any changes for the Status Value ?

Comment: Like this clockStatusRef = firebase.database().ref("games/"+gameId+"/Score/Clock/Status");
 clockStatusRef.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  var status = snapshot.val();

Comment: Part of my problem was also fact that i had also the folowing code in my script var dbref = firebase.database().ref("games/"+gameId+"/Score/");dbref.on('value',function(snapshot){var data = snapshot.val();

This loaded the initial data for my app but it seems on change the first one will get hit if there is multiple listner not the most specific. So for now i changed it to once

Comment: Ok i am getting closer, the below code fires on change 
var dbref = firebase.database().ref("games/"+gameId+"/Score/Clock");
   dbref.on("child_changed",function(snapshot){
  var status = snapshot.val();
but how do i see what field was changed as var staus will hold the value of the field change but i dont know which one ?

Answer (score 0):

As there seem to be some limitation as far as what is triggered when multiple listeners looking for changes and data overlaps i changed my code. As my App does not have any heavy traffic so changes are not that often, i use one listener for changes and to address my issue i just went ahead and added the run once for the initial setup then run different code on updates. Would have been nice to control what listener gets the notification of change, also the child_changed seems to have its limitations as i got it to fire but was not able to tell which child actually changed.